# NTP - chronyd - unable to read socket on port 123 (worked when used ntpd)

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I'm trying to read the NTP status on red hat linux server, but I'm getting socket timeout receive error
**java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out**

This code works when run against a system using ntpd but not for chronyd?

I expect it's a configuration issue? I've run chronyc tracker and all looks good.

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Chrony is a NTP v4 server, which is backwards compatible with a NTP v3 client at best. The code we are using to query the server follows the NTP v2 protocol, which is why it does not work.